# How to install Dropbox in elementary OS?

Tags: release-freya

How to install Dropbox in elementary OS? I am getting errors and core dump!

```
tushar@Inspiron-7537:~$ dropbox start -i
Starting Dropbox...Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(dropbox:8008): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(dropbox:8008): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I was also getting `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module` but I managed to remove that error by installing `canberra-gtk-module`

Comment: Ditto. Also I'd like to figure how to "properly" install it, since Elementary has an actual goal in consistent experience for users.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to install Dropbox from Git and running a script.

I followed the instructions mentioned here: https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox

Comment: Do you know a way that goes through offical repo rather than a third party script and direct upstream download as the script at zant95/elementary-dropbox you suggested?